# Smooth map to the stack of G-bundles 

Tags: stacks, ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ a semisimple group and $B$ a Borel subgroup.
We denote by $Bun_{G}$ the stack of G-bundles.

Is it true that a certain open subset $Bun_{B,r}$ maps smoothly to $Bun_{G}$?

My question comes from Lemma 14 .2.1 from
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611323.pdf

but I'm not sure to understand well.

Comment: You need to formulate the question more precisely - in this way it is obvious (any map between reduced algebraic stacks locally of finite type is generically smooth).

Comment: I fixed the typo in your title, which you can also do if you notice them in future.

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the map from the stack of $H$-bundles to the stack of $G$-bundles is a fiber bundle with fiber $G/H$.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the lemma 14.2.1 then, why restricting to an open subset if everything is already smooth with connected fibers?


Comment: Angelo: what you wrote is wrong (it is only true for bundles over a point).

Comment: For example, the fiber over the trivial $G$-bundles on some scheme $X$ is the space of maps from $X$ to $G/H$.

Comment: Oops, sorry, was thinking of classifying stacks.

Comment: In my case, $Bun_{B,r}$ corresponds to the open substack obtained by base change from the analog open substack $\Bun_{T,r}$ consisting of $T$-torsors E such that $H^{1}(X,E\times^{T}V)=0$ for any representation $V$ of $T$ which appear as subquotients of $Lie(U^{-})$ where $U^{-}$ is the opposite unipotent radical of $B$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is the following: for a $G$-torsor $E_G$ over $C$ and for the associated projective scheme $E_{G,B} := E_G/B$, a lift $E_B$ of $E_G$ to a $B$-torsor over $C$ is the same thing as a section $\sigma:C\to E_{G,B}$ of the projection $\pi:E_{G,B}\to C$.  Via infinitesimal deformation theory of the Hilbert scheme, this section is unobstructed if $H^1(C,\sigma^*(\Omega_\pi)^\vee)$ is zero.  Finally, $\sigma^*(\Omega_\pi)^\vee$ turns out to be $E_B \times^B \text{Lie}(U^{-})$.  In fact, since $E_B$ has a further reduction of structure group to a maximal torus $T$, i.e., $E_B$ equals $B \times^T E_T$ for a $T$-torsor $E_T$, the bundle $E_B\times^B \text{Lie}(U^{-})$ turns out to equal $E_T\times^T \text{Lie}(U^{-})$, which splits as a direct sum of invertible sheaves on $C$ (because every representation of $T$ is a direct sum of characters).  Thus $E^T\times^T \text{Lie}(U^{-})$ has vanishing $h^1$ if and only if each of these summands has vanishing $h^1$.  That is precisely the condition imposed by Gaitsgory and Nadler to define the open subset $\text{Bun}_{B,r}$ inside $\text{Bun}_B$.